# How to mutate JavaScript const array when it assigned to another const array

Tags: javascript

I have the below code

```
const a = [1,2];
const b = a;

b.push(3);
console.log(a); //[1,2,3]
console.log(b); //[1,2,3]
```

Can anyone explain me what happens here and how I can only mutate "b" array instead of adding "3" to array "a"

Comment: Make a copy of the array instead of referencing the original one

Comment: const b = [...a] use of spread operator resolved my question. Above comment helped me lot. Thanks